# Calling another constructor from a constructor in PHP

Tags: php, constructor, multiple-constructors

I want a few constructors defined in a PHP class. However, my code for the constructors is currently very similar. I would rather not repeat code if possible. Is there a way to call other constructors from within one constructor in a php class? Is there a way to have multiple constructors in a PHP class?

```
function __construct($service, $action)
{
    if(empty($service) || empty($action))
    {
        throw new Exception("Both service and action must have a value");
    }
    $this->$mService = $service;
    $this->$mAction = $action;

    $this->$mHasSecurity = false;
}
function __construct($service, $action, $security)
    {
        __construct($service, $action); // This is what I want to be able to do, so I don't have to repeat code

        if(!empty($security))
        {
            $this->$mHasSecurity = true;
            $this->$mSecurity = $security;
        }
    }
```

I know that I could solve this by creating for instance some Init methods. But is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't overload functions like that in PHP. If you do this:

```
class A {
  public function __construct() { }
  public function __construct($a, $b) { }
}
```

your code won't compile with an error that you can't redeclare `__construct()`.

The way to do this is with optional arguments.

```
function __construct($service, $action, $security = '') {
  if (empty($service) || empty($action)) {
    throw new Exception("Both service and action must have a value");
  }
  $this->$mService = $service;
  $this->$mAction = $action;
  $this->$mHasSecurity = false;
  if (!empty($security)) {
    $this->$mHasSecurity = true;
    $this->$mSecurity = $security;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

And if you really have to have completely different arguments, use the Factory pattern.

```
class Car {       
   public static function createCarWithDoors($intNumDoors) {
       $objCar = new Car();
       $objCar->intDoors = $intNumDoors;
       return $objCar;
   }

   public static function createCarWithHorsepower($intHorsepower) {
       $objCar = new Car();
       $objCar->intHorses = $intHorsepower;
       return $objCar;
   }
}

$objFirst = Car::createCarWithDoors(3);
$objSecond = Car::createCarWithHorsePower(200);
```